# accidentally set my main folder as shared in public place

Tags: network

I just figured my main folder under my user and everything in it was shared. Is there a log on my computer that checks whether someone downloaded from my computer? I remember there was somebody else with a mac on the same network and had the opportunity to download all my private information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a method to do that. Anyhow, I bet that the chances of that happening are very small. First, the person would have to have no morals, and second, the person would have had to specifically look for a shared folder, and that is also relatively unlikely. Also, just to be safe, monitor what can be monitored to discover whether your information was taken for a few days/weeks.

Comment: I guess that makes a lot of sense what you're saying. Quite a number of people are relatively decent in reality. Not in the newspaper of course. How do you monitor if information was taken?

Comment: I don't think its possible.

Comment: If you had passwords or login details stored for bank accounts or other services you might consider changing them. Though I myself wouldnt be too worried in this situation, the person would have to have been specifically targeting you - otherwise I doubt they would have taken any information. Always important to share folders with passwords. if you dont have a password, you can create a sharing only account and tick the remember box on any computers you regularly use.